# Only first 3 (of 7) Anchored-links (using ID's) working (going to correct place) in Firefox (all work in Chrome & Safari)

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, hyperlink, anchor

Ok, I'm working on a scrolling site (using jQuery) with one exterior page. Withing this exterior page there are navigation links to go back to the scrolling page. I have added unique ID's (eg. `<div id="done">` ) to each section on the scrolling page and have added # anchor points to the end of the links in the exterior page (eg. `<a href="index-banners.html#done">What We've Done</a>` ).

These work in Safari and Chrome. But only The first 3 (from the top of the page down) work in FF. The rest take me to the bottom of the page.

If I type the URL of the scrolling page with an # extension to one of the ID's that aren't working in FF, it works and takes me to the correct point. I have tried removeing the jQuery occurring after the working anchor points and they still wouldn't work. However, removing some `<ul>`'s that the jQuery effects did allow the links to find their respective points. This is mealy an observation as those `<ul>`'s must remain.

Can anyone tell me why and how I can fix/workaround?

Here is a link to the test page (http://www.irishofcourse.co.cc/firebrand/index-banners.html). Head to "what we do" then click the "find out more" link to the exterior page, or go straight to the exterior page here (http://www.irishofcourse.co.cc/firebrand/index-do.html). Note: the anchored links to "What We've Done", "Case Studies" and "Social" are the ones not working.

Ben.

Answer (score 0):

To do anchor links you need `<a name="anchor">` to "scroll" to and `<a href="#anchor">` as link.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Though I read linking to ID's is better practice now, I have also tried the name= method too, with the same result. As stated the first 3 work and they all work in Safari+Chrome.

Comment: I tested you're page again on all my browsers and in all browsers the site behaves the same. I click on the navigation bar on the left and the page is scrolling down and up the anchors. when I click "what we do" and on "find out more" you will move to a new page. After using the navigation ALL links behave strange depending on browser.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm experiencing, though to be more specific FireFox is the browser not handling them well, and indeed the one that I'm concerned about. Any guesses as to why?

Comment: can you post the jquery code for the function to do the anchor scrolling?

Comment: There is no jQuery function for the anchor links. The links on the exterior page look like this `<a href="index-banners.html#done">What We've Done</a>`. They are linked to the ID tags used within the main page. The scrolling in on the main page uses jQuery but that is working fine.

Comment: Hmmm, when I click on the link, the correct page is showing, but disapears and the page is loading again (the red bar appears) and it goes to the wrong page.